# Accessing internet on RPi 3B via ethernet using ZTE dongle

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to access internet on Raspberry Pi 3B over Ethernet but for the last three days I have not been able to do it. I am using ZTE 3G dongle plugged into my PC to access internet on PC. Kindly tell me how to share its internet to Raspberry.

Comment: "over Ethernet" -- do you have an Ethernet cable? It appears that you do, and that it fails to work. If so, your question should be "Ethernet cable not working". However, if that's not your question, you'll have to specify if you want to share internet between the PC and RPi, with the dongle plugged into the PC; OR the dongle plugged into RPi.

Comment: You appear to be asking how to set internet sharing on an unknown computer, running an unknown OS - nothing to do with Pi

Comment: Some confusion.  (1) Ethernet is a wired thing, using colour cables, usually CAT 5/6 twisted wire cables.  (2) ZTE 3G is 3G Wifi, ... https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/Zte-3g-modem-sans-fil-mf70-hspa-modem-3g-wifi-carte-sim-usb-dongle-wifi-dongle/32832197833.html?spm=a2g0w.search0604.3.57.6f0a6f2eQq7eoh&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0%2Csearchweb201602_9_10065_10068_319_10059_10884_317_10887_10696_321_322_10084_453_10083_454_10103_10618_10307_537_536%2Csearchweb201603_51%2CppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=4c2baafb-cb7e-416d-adea-2b61c45eedd3&algo_expid=4c2baafb-cb7e-416d-adea-2b61c45eedd3-8